# Data Structures Asymptotic notations

Tags: data-structures, computer-science, asymptotic-complexity

What will be the answer to " Tell Any one complexity of notation"  . It was asked in my data structure theory paper, i can't understand the question.

Will it be Big o notation, big omega notation, big theta, one of these

or Big oh and ( http://bigocheatsheet.com/)   a value from here like O(n^2)

Comment: I can't understand the question either

Comment: Tell Any one complexity of notation

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. Could you provide more context?

Comment: It has do with asymptotic notations of algoritms in data Structure. the notations are , big oh, theta small thet etc. The questions asks to tell any 1 complexity of notation.

Comment: Perhaps they want you to explain one of them?